# EV SSL Certificate / Changing WHOIS Business Name and Contact Info

Tags: ssl, dns

Situation:  The company has been sold and wants me to update the WHOIS information to reflect the new ownership. We currently have an valid EV SSL Certificate issued to the old company that displays "ABC Corp" in the green address bar. After the domain name registration is updated, WHOIS will return a "XYZ Inc", with different address and contact information.  At that point we will apply for a new EV SSL Certificate.

Question:  In the interim, while we are waiting for the new EV SSL cert, could the WHOIS change affect customers using the existing SSL EV Certificate when connecting to the site?  For example, will Chrome not display the green padlock due to the WHOIS mismatch?

My working understanding is that the existing EV SSL Certificate should work just fine until we replace it. That the WHOIS record is only checked by the CA when the certificate is issued and that browsers (Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari) do not check WHOIS. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks,

Rocky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHOIS information is not used in the client validation of certificates, EV or otherwise.  So if WHOIS information changes, an existing EV certificate will continue to work exactly as before (unless it or a certificate in its trust chain is revoked or expires).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  -  Rocky